# DeleteElement for Binary Search Tree is giving runtime error?

Tags: c, data-structures, struct, binary-search-tree

I am trying to write a function called 'DeleteElement' for deleting an element in Binary Search Tree.It compiles properly but it is giving runtime error. Please help me debug the error. Thanks in advance.

```
C Code:

#include <stdio.h>
#include <malloc.h>


struct BinaryTree
{
         int data;
         struct BinaryTree *left;
         struct BinaryTree *right;
};


int FindMin(struct BinaryTree *root)
{
    if(root == NULL)
    {
        return NULL;
    }
    while(root->left)
    {
        root = root->left;
    }
return root->data;

}


int FindMax(struct BinaryTree *root)
{
    if(root == NULL)
    {
        return NULL;
    }
    while(root->right)
    {
        root = root->right;
    }
return root->data;
}



struct BinaryTree *DeleteElement(struct BinaryTree *root,int element)
{
    struct BinaryTree *temp;
    if(root == NULL)
    {
        printf("Element Not found");
        //return NULL;
    }
    else if(element > root->data)
    {
        root->right = DeleteElement(root->right,element);
    }
    else if(element < root->data)
    {
        root->left = DeleteElement(root->left,element);
    }
    else
    {
        if(root->left && root->right)
        {
            int temp1 = FindMax(root->left);
            root->data = temp1; 
            root->left = DeleteElement(root->left,root->data);
        }
        else 
        {
            temp = root;
            if(root->left == NULL)
            {
                root = root->right;
            }
            if(root->right == NULL)
            {
                root = root->left;
            }
            free(temp);
        }
    }
    return root;
}

int main()
{
    struct BinaryTree * root = (struct BinaryTree *)malloc(sizeof(struct BinaryTree));
    root-> data = 7;
    struct BinaryTree * l = (struct BinaryTree *)malloc(sizeof(struct BinaryTree));
    l -> data = 4;
    struct BinaryTree * ll = (struct BinaryTree *)malloc(sizeof(struct BinaryTree));
    ll -> data = 2;
    ll -> left = ll -> right = NULL;
    struct BinaryTree * lr = (struct BinaryTree *)malloc(sizeof(struct BinaryTree));
    lr -> data = 5;
    lr -> left = lr -> right = NULL;
    l -> left = ll;
    l -> right = lr;
    struct BinaryTree * r = (struct BinaryTree *)malloc(sizeof(struct BinaryTree));
    r -> data = 9;
    struct BinaryTree * rl = (struct BinaryTree *)malloc(sizeof(struct BinaryTree));
    rl -> data = 8;
    rl -> left = rl -> right = NULL;
    struct BinaryTree * rr = (struct BinaryTree *)malloc(sizeof(struct BinaryTree));
    rr -> data = 11;
    rr -> left = rr -> right = NULL;
    r -> left = rl;
    r -> right = rr;
    root -> left = l;
    root -> right = r;


    printf("Max %d\n",FindMax(root));
    printf("Min %d\n",FindMin(root));
    DeleteElement(root,2);
    printf("Max %d\n",FindMax(root));
    printf("Min %d\n",FindMin(root));
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Please provide the code where you're using this function

Comment: Everything looks good in this function. As @teivaz pointed out, there might be a problem in the calling context.

Comment: I have updated to include the full code.Now can you see any error?

Comment: What is the runtime error you get ?

Comment: Just Runtime error

Comment: Can you run the code and check?

Comment: I've run the code on my IDE and it seems there is a problem with the line `if(root->right == NULL)`. I see that `root` is `NULL` when the program reaches that line.

Comment: 'root' will be equal to 'element' at that point?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**THE PROBLEM :**

The problem resides in the following lines :

```
if(root->left == NULL)
{
  root = root->right;
}
if(root->right == NULL)
{
  root = root->left;
}
```

The first condition might be true and the program will change the value of `root`. But the second `if` statement will still be evaluated, and since `root` might have been changed to `NULL` in the previous statement there can be a runtime error. (Trying to access a field of `NULL` is never a good thing)

**THE FIX :**

You should change the second `if` by an `else if` like this :

```
if(root->left == NULL)
{
  root = root->right;
}
else if(root->right == NULL)
{
  root = root->left;
}
```